# PHP Multiple sets of radio buttons colliding

Tags: php, html, arrays, radio-button

I'm trying to separate a few sections that all have the same name attribute for each input.

```
<div class="section">
 <h4>Radio-option</h4>
 <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="yes" />Yes
 <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="no" />no
</div>

<div class="section">
 <h4>Radio-option</h4>
 <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="yes" />Yes
 <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="no" />no
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="functionToAddAnotherSection()" value="Add Section" />
```

These div sections can be added, duplicated and even sorted (jQuery sortable). I don't have any ID keys for these sections, they're all mashed into an array and when they're being displayed again, i simply break the array and put each value in each section.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is

Comment: And... what is your question?

Comment: You should assign at least an ID or something to give a property to any section.. Else, how you're supposed to gather any information?

Comment: So, give your 2nd set of radios a different name or give them different values. If that's not what you're asking, then be more specific using an example.

Comment: Haha sorry been awake for a long time now getting really tired. When i check a radio-button in the first section, it also checks (or unchecks) the other radio buttons with the same name and value in the other sections. Is there any simple way to separate these?

Comment: So, you need to give a different name per group

Comment: If you want to keep the `[]`-syntax to get an array of values in PHP – then specify the _index_ yourself: `radio_array[0]` for the first group, `radio_array[1]` for the second, etc.

Comment: @CBroe that might work actually. Currently i'm using a dropdown-list instead that works. Checkboxes works too but i only want 1 option to be selected. I don't see why radio-buttons are struggling so much :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to either give each set of radio buttons a unique `name`, OR place each set of radio buttons into their own `<form>` element.

Either of these should fix your problem. Which one you use really depends on how you're handling the data on the server side:

**Unique `form` elements:**

```
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h4>Radio-option</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="no" />no
  </form>
</div>

<div class="section">
 <h4>Radio-option</h4>
  <form>
    <h4>Radio-option</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="no" />no
  </form>
</div>
```

**Unique names:**

```
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h4>Radio-option</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array_section1[]" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array_section1[]" value="no" />no
  </form>
</div>

<div class="section">
 <h4>Radio-option</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_array_section2[]" value="yes" />Yes
  <input type="radio" name="radio_array_section2[]" value="no" />no
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the way i handle the data is pretty complex. As mentioned, the sections can be added, duplicated and re-sorted, and therefore i don't really know how to add a name to each of these sections without messing them up when they're being sorted or added. Using <form> would be an issue aswell, since it will only post the first <form> and ignore the other ones. This is a wordpress meta-box i'm working on, maybe it helps

Comment: Using CBroe's answer is probably the only way to go, then. Specify the names as indices of the array: `radio_array[0]`, `radio_array[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested arrays

```
<form>
    <div class="section">
        <h4>Radio-option</h4>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_array[0][]" value="yes" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radio_array[0][]" value="no" />no
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <h4>Radio-option</h4>
        <input type="radio" name="radio_array[1][]" value="yes" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radio_array[1][]" value="no" />no
    </div>

    ...
        <input type="radio" name="radio_array[2][]" value="yes" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radio_array[2][]" value="no" />no
    ...
</form>
```

... and so on.

Comment: why is this not the accepted answer this seems to be genius... i could be wrong its been a while since i used php but couldnt you also go with radio_array['section_name'][]. rather then numbered indices.